# Referencing multiple ridigbodies and colliders on child objects

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a character with multiple rigidbodies and colliders on child objects that I would like to reference. Preferably on an individual level so I can determine which side of my cube character is colliding. You can see my hierarchy in the gif below.

I have some code working, but I can only make it work if I have the script on every child gameobject. Ultimately I would like one script on the parent object that creates a list/array of the rigidbodies and colliders and groups them into "sides".

[Here are my project files](https://www.dropbox.com/s/61ne973w2cw5sdo/jellycube.unitypackage?dl=0) & this is my broken code so far. Please can someone take a look and point me in the right direction. Should I be using GetComponentsInChildren?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityStandardAssets.CrossPlatformInput;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private float m_JumpPower = 1; // The force added to the jelly when it jumps.
    private bool jump;
    Rigidbody rigArray;


    private void Start ()
    {
        // Start function

        GameObject[] objs = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("RigObject");
        List<Rigidbody> list = new List<Rigidbody>();
        for (int i = 0; i < objs.Length; i++)
        {
            Rigidbody rig = objs[i].GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
            rigList.Add(rig);
        }
        rigArray = list.ToArray();
    }

    private void Update ()
    {
        jump = CrossPlatformInputManager.GetButton("Jump");

        if (jump)
        {
            Debug.Log("Jumping");
            rigArray.AddForce(Vector3.up * m_JumpPower, ForceMode.Impulse);
        }
    }

}
```

[image: You can see my hierarchy in the gif below.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [Component.GetComponentsInChildren](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.GetComponentsInChildren.html). This can be specified with the `Rigidbody` object and get all the rigidbodies in the children of the parent. You can then use `tags` of the GameObject that the rigidbody is attached to to identify the rigidbodies. For example, tagging the child object with `LEFT_SIDE` to get the left side rigidbody.

To add a force to all rigidbodies:

```
public Rigidbody[] Rigidbodies;
...
Rigidbodies = GetComponentsInChildren<Rigidbody>();
...
foreach(Rididbody rb in Rigidbodies){
     rb.AddForce(Vector3.up * m_JumpPower, ForceMode.Impulse);
}
```

Comment: I think I get what you're saying, but I'm getting an error and I'm not sure why. [Here's my code.](https://pastebin.com/Tqs5eVDS)


_Assets/Scripts/Player.cs(24,25): error CS1061: Type `UnityEngine.Component[]' does not contain a definition for `AddForce' and no extension method `AddForce' of type `UnityEngine.Component[]' could be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?_

Comment: You are attempting to add a force to an array of components. Instead of making it a component array, make it a Rigidbody array and use a `foreach` loop to add the forces

Comment: Incredible, it works! Thank you! Will colliders work the same way?

Comment: It doesn't look like OnCollisionEnter messages will fire on my parent object, only the children with the Rigidbody.

Comment: Collisions are determined by the collider locations, not the rigidbody locations. Where are you colliders located?

Comment: On the child components, you can see them in the .gif

Comment: I can't view the gif on my current internet restrictions in the workplace, but this is probably best suited for another question